# How do I convert a 64bit number to hexadecimal in excel?

Tags: excel

I'm trying `DEC2HEX(1000000000050000000)` but it comes out as #NUM! as the number is too large for this function.

Is there another function I could use to turn this number into hexadecimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free add-in available that will handle that:  [Xnumbers](http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm)

Seems to work OK:

```
=cvDecBase("1000000000050000000",16) -->  DE0B6B3AA5EF080
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to convert a decimal number to a 64 bit hex string, assuming that the decimal number is in cell A1 you can use the following:

```
=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(A1/2^32),DEC2HEX(MOD(A1,2^32),8))
```

This will work up to decimal value of 18,446,744,073,709,500,000 or hex value of 0xfffffffffffff800.

**Bonus:**

To convert from hex string to decimal, assuming that the 64bit hex string is in cell A1 and contains 16-characters then you can use the following:

```
=HEX2DEC(LEFT(A1,8))*2^32+HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A1,8))
```

You can adjust the number of characters in the LEFT(text,[num_chars]) to better suit your needs.

If your hex string has a 0x then you can use the following:

```
=HEX2DEC(MID(A1,3,8))*2^32+HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A1,8))
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a simple solution for converting HEX to DEC and vice versa without the limits of characters.

**HEX to DEC**: use DECIMAL(input number or cell coordinates, **input** base number)

- Case 1: I want to convert hex value "3C" to decimal, the formula is DECIMAL(3C, 16).
- Case 2: I want to convert binary value "1001" to decimal, the formula is DECIMAL(1001, 2).

**DEC to HEX**: use BASE(input number or cell coordinates, **output** base number)

- Case 1:I want to convert number value "1500" to hexadecimal, the formula is BASE(1500, 16)
- Case 2:I want to convert number value "1500" to binary, the formula is BASE(1500, 2)

Answer (score 4):

The DEC2HEX function has a limit of `549,755,813,887`, try this formula it works for numbers up to 281,474,976,710,655.

`=DEC2HEX(A7/(16^9),3)&DEC2HEX(MOD(A7,16^9),9)`

Comment: Unfortunately I need a solution that works for numbers greater than 281,474,976,710,655

Answer (score 0):

Long formula but it is working for 64-HEX characters:

```
=HEX2DEC(MID(A24,1,8))*2^512 *(4) +HEX2DEC(MID(A24,9,8))*2^512 *(2) +HEX2DEC(MID(A24,17,8))*2^512+HEX2DEC(MID(A24,25,8))*2^256+HEX2DEC(MID(A24,33,8))*2^128+HEX2DEC(MID(A24,41,8))*2^64+HEX2DEC(MID(A24,49,8))*2^32+HEX2DEC(MID(A24,57,8))
```

please note: `(*4) = *4` (remove brackets) and: `(*2) = *2` (remove brackets)

also note: all 64 character must be present like the following example:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fd1
```